# VC++ Glew external linking errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, glew

so I have this project for my graphics class that I need to complete using C++ and OpenGL. I am using VS2013 and VC++ to complete the project. The first example we were given built successfully and ran fine. However, when we were given the code for the second project, I get a bunch of linking errors (below) where Mac and Linux computers were able to compile and run just fine. I have been through numerous blogs on and off of stack overflow, and have been unable to resolve this issue.

I've also replaced all the libraries and dlls and headers both from the pre-packaged download from the glut website, and I also compiled the source code of glut and placed the lib, dll, and header files into the correct folder and still get the same error.

The libraries here *must* be dynamic, they cannot be static (as per request of my professor).

The source code can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/nolanblew/cs-150-project-2/overview, and then click on "download" or you can fork it (please don't push to this repo - it will be public until this question is answered).

Here are all of the link errors I'm getting. The code compiles fine but fails on build:

```
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttribPointer    C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewUseProgram C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniformMatrix4fv   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform3f  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform1i  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewShaderSource   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewLinkProgram        C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetUniformLocation C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetShaderiv    C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetProgramiv   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetObjectParameterivARB    C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetInfoLogARB  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetAttribLocation  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray    C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   27  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDisableVertexAttribArray   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDetachShader   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteShader   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteProgram  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   11  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewCreateShader   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewCreateProgram  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewCompileShader  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   36  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindFragDataLocation   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindBuffer C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewAttachShader   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\glsupport.obj  Project 2
Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewActiveTexture  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   37  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___GLEW_VERSION_2_0   C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\trans.obj  Project 2
Error   38  error LNK1120: 29 unresolved externals  C:\Users\Nolan\Source\Repos\cs-150-project-2\Debug\Project 2.exe    Project 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well after a lot of research I found out what to do on this page: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/472791-beginner-woes-linking-solved/

Basically,

> In VC++, click View>Propery Pages...
>
> Expand Configuration Properties>Linker>Input
>
> add glew32.lib (for example) to the Additional Dependencies box